# Simple math with string by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have two divs:

```
<span class='green price'>1.999$</span>
<span class='blue price'>299$</span>
```

I was convert variable to this strings:

```
var termPrice = $(".blue").html();
var setupPrice = $(".green").html();
```

And I want to math with this variables:

```
var totalPrice = termPrice + setupPrice;
```

But I can not get the results I wanted. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `parseFloat();` the value, otherwise you'll be attempting to add two strings.

```
<span id="one" class='green price'>1.999</span>
<span id="two" class='blue price'>299</span>

var one = parseFloat($("#one").text());
var two = parseInt($("#two").text());
var res = one + two;

alert(res);
// 300.999
```

**Example 1:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ogn4Ldwv/

**Edit 1**

Another example where you can keep your *$* signs in your `HTML`.

```
<span id="one" class='green price'>1.999$</span>
<span id="two" class='blue price'>299$</span>

var one = parseFloat($("#one").text().replace("/$/", ""));
var two = parseInt($("#two").text().replace("/$/", ""));
var res = one + two;

alert(res);
```

**Example 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/ogn4Ldwv/1/

Comment: @JonathanD. and that is what `parseFloat` is for. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: Yes, thank you but when we addition these two values ​​it does not result 300.999 It must be 2.248$.